# Tomcat - how to store sessions in DB immediately?

Tags: tomcat, jdbc

I'm experimenting with tomcat JDBCStore-based session persistence and wonder whether there is a way to make tomcat store sessions in DB as soon as possible?

I've tried to play with `minIdleSwap` and `maxIdleSwap` values, but I guess I just don't understand what actually those parameters are standing for, though I've read the [documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/manager.html).

Answer (score 1):

I think you need the [maxIdleBackup setting](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/session/PersistentManagerBase.html#setMaxIdleBackup%28int%29). From the linked javadoc:

> Sets the option to back sessions up to the Store after they are used
>   in a request. Sessions remain available in memory after being backed
>   up, so they are not passivated as they are when swapped out. The value
>   set indicates how old a session may get (since its last use) before it
>   must be backed up: `-1` means sessions are not backed up.
>
> Note that this is not a hard limit: sessions are checked against this
>   age limit periodically according to `processExpiresFrequency`. This
>   value should be considered to indicate when a session is ripe for
>   backing up.
>
> So it is possible that a session may be idle for `maxIdleBackup` +
>   `processExpiresFrequency` * `engine.backgroundProcessorDelay` seconds,
>   plus the time it takes to handle other session expiration, swapping,
>   etc. tasks.

Comment: nope, this setting is just ignored, at least when I'm trying to set it to -1.

Comment: @shabunc Look again. '-1 means sessions are not backed up'. That's not what you asked about.